# Interpretation of: "I discussed the subject of the paper with someone"

Tags: usage, expressions

Suppose, I've written a paper "On Blue Cats" and told somebody that "I discussed the subject of the paper with Brown". How will this be understood?

Will it mean that

1. We discussed blue cats: their origin and behavior, say.

or

2. Brown argued that I should have chosen another subject and written about, say, violet mice

Comment: With no more context, I'd pick (2), because there are more natural ways to express (1), but it is ambiguous and could mean either.

Comment: @hunter - Really? For me, it's definitely #1. I don't know where #2 is coming from. But I agree that it's vague. "Discussing the subject of the paper" could mean any of several things, e.g.: arguing about the chosen topic, praising the chosen topic, or summarizing the paper's contents.

Comment: Having some context, especially with regards to time, would make this much clearer.  "Before I started writing, we discussed a number of subjects.  I then chose 'blue cats'" = he helped me choose the subject. "After I had my outline, we discussed the subject" = he taught me about the subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with using the expression **subject of the paper** (or a book) is that it can mean either a [topic](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/topic)- a tag for what the paper is about, or the actual person or thing that the book describes. Only context will indicate the intended meaning.

What I would say to describe the two possible meanings would be:

> We discussed the paper

This says that you discussed the paper generally: this could include the title, topic, authors, content, references, etc, etc.

> We discussed the topic of the paper

This says that you discussed (purely as tags) what the book is, or should have been, about.

Comment: Sorry, I still do not quite understand: "you discussed what the paper is about", so we discussed cats not the choice of subject?

Comment: @Serguei, I have updated my answer to try to make it clearer.